How to specify which WireMock stub JSON file to use in each test case?
I have some integration tests which use WireMock for stubbing external HTTP requests. All of the stubs are located in a mappings directory and are all automatically picked up by the tests.
I would like to set it up so that WireMock doesn't automatically pickup the stubs and I have to explicitly state in each test case which stubs files apply. Is there a way of doing this?

Often the best way to achieve this is to create the stubs just in time, programmatically, in the setup part of your test cases.
Then you reset WireMock at the end of each test case so you're always starting with a clean slate. The JUnit 5 extension @WireMockTest can handle this lifecycle for you.
An alternative approach is to ensure that your stubs match specific request data that's only sent by particular test cases, so e.g. if your test case tries to load a user with ID 12345 then you'd configure a stub for /users/12345 and ensure that no other test case uses this ID.
